# PHP If & Else Statement in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, graphical-logo

I'm trying to figure out how to do a if else statement in Wordpress. I want it to state if `$data[0]['media_upload']` is empty then show the blog title. Else *(if there is something there)* show the logo in Wordpress. I'm wondering if I have the wrong syntax.

Right now I have the following which is showing the blog title and no errors but I do have a image uploaded and its not showing for some reason. Any ideas would be great!

```
<?php
if (empty($data[0]['media_upload'])) {
echo'<h1 class="site-title"><a href="';
  esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
echo'" title="';
  esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) );
echo'" rel="home">';
  bloginfo( 'name' );
echo'</a></h1>';
}

else{
echo '<a href="';
  bloginfo('siteurl');
    echo '">';
echo'<img src="';
  global $data; 
  $data['media_upload']; 
echo'" /></a>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong w/ the if/else.  Most likely `empty($data[0]['media_upload']` never has a non-empty value.

Comment: okay, hummm. I wonder why. Instead of empty can I change it to a ' '? That may not make sense.

Comment: This is how I'm normally calling it when it works fine. <?php global $data; echo $data['media_upload']; ?>

Comment: How did you get $data in the first place? That will help us answer your question, what does it display when you echo it?

Comment: when I echo what I have above it shows the image that I've uploaded in the admin interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
echo'<img src="';
global $data; 
$data[0]['media_upload']; 
      ^ // you forgot 0th index
echo'" /></a>';
```

Comment: I don't think I want the [0] in either of them... I took it out and am getting results but now my html is showing... <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress"><img src="" /></a> so I need to find the source still but making progress. This helped me out but I took out the [0] and echoed $data['media_upload']; and it worked! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @b-lew So why are you checking `$data[0]['media_upload']` is empty or not?

Comment: its not. I screwed up initially by putting in $data[0] my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:
`$data['media_upload'];`
in your else to: `$data[0]['media_upload'];`
like you have in your if statement (or the other way around). We don't really know what $data is so it's hard to help you.

Edit: Since I can't comment yet, I'll comment here. 
Try using the [rubber duck technique](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html); explain to us what is happening with the $data object in your code. Maybe you'll figure it out yourself.